# Google Map API requesting a new key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I added the google maps API v2 to a website I'm currently working on. I'm not having any issue with the maps but the other users are receiving an error message requesting a new key for this API. I've tried generating a new key but the users are still receiving this error. I made sure to allow any referers to make sure it's not causing any problems.
 Is there something else than the API key that could cause this error? *At this point, I'm pretty sure the key should be working since I don't have the problem on my end*.
 Is it possible that the cache needs to be removed on the user end to correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: a new key is requested if the source domain is different from the one you declared during the registration. Example: Key works on www.olivier.com, key doesn't works on www.parenteau.com even if the source file are the same. Even subdomains must be a problem... maps.olivier.com should show the errore message too. Please ensure you and your users points to the same exact domain.

Comment: Also consider migrating to V3 as V2 has been deprecated. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @Davide Berra I'm not sure I understand which source domain you're referring to. As far as I can remember, it didn't ask for a domain when I registered my project. I thought those subdomains would be determined by the referers of the API key and I'm currently allowing any referers.

Comment: @rwhite35 I wish I could do that but it's the system used in the company I'm working in.

Comment: @Olivier Parenteau , the problem occours with EVERY user (other than you) or just to someone? Can you check if the html source of the page downloaded by an user with the problem, is aligned with the last version or just loaded a cached page?

Comment: Anyway with source domain i was talking about the list of domains (or ips) editable through the google api access panel with the button "Edit allowed referers". Look at the points 5-6-7-8 here [CLICK ME](http://www.openpotion.com/clients/knowledgebase/7/Getting-Google-Maps-API-Code.html)

Comment: The problem with the list of domains is that it's currently set to allow all referers. I just verified on another user computer and it is an issue with the cached version of the website.